# Issue with using GMail SMTP from Payara 5 Java Mail

Tags: smtp, jakarta-mail, glassfish-5

I have just written a test standalone Java Mail Application to send an email from my gmail A/C to the outlook one and it works like a charm. Below are the essential properties for the Mail Session:

```
props.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com");
props.put("mail.smtp.port", "465");
props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", "465");
props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class", "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");
props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
```

However, moment I configure the same properties in the Glassfish 5 Java Email Session (on Admin console), I see the following error in the log, upon running the web application:

```
 StandardWrapperValve[Faces Servlet]: Servlet.service() for servlet Faces Servlet threw exception
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.setApplicationProtocols([Ljava/lang/String;)V
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.initHandshaker(SSLSocketImpl.java:1350)
```

PS - "Less secure app access" on Google A/C is set to ON for both the cases.

Puzzled! Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: See: [JDK-8213936](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8213936)

Comment: @jmehrens. Thanks for your input but I am afraid that the above link that you have mentioned pertains to JDBC issue whereas mine is regarding "email securely".

Comment: The last comment in the ticket is "I assume this is caused by the `glassfish/modules/endorsed/grizzly-npn-bootstrap.jar` that contains `sun.security.ssl` package, which is no longer compatible with JDK 8u191+"  Have you tried to downgrade OpenJDK to see if that works around the issue?

Comment: @jmehrens. Thanks for the comment. I tried everything with  JDK 8u191 and unfortunately, I continue to see the same error.

Comment: You have to use a version less than 191.  191 is going to show the same issue.